# Excel double left click in cell with getpivotdata want go to the pivot table

Tags: excel

I have seen in someone double left click a cell with GETPIVOTDATA and went directly to the pivot table. I tried in my Excel but it does not work. Is there any settings that I have to change to make it work?

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0):

A college just showed me the answer!

In File->Options->Advanced->Editing options->remove the check in '**Allow editing directlt in cells**'

[image]